# Google People API not returning any data

Tags: google-api

I am using this url:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=emailAddresses&access_token=XYZ...
```

The access token is valid, I have requested scope userinfo.profile.  The call returns with http code 200, however all the data I get is:

```
{
    "resourceName": "people/106663430887168632038",
    "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoEAQIFBw=="
}
```

Why am I not getting the email address?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found this API that retrieves the email address I want:

```
 https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/profile
```

I guess the People API retrieves some other stored email addresses.